# railsのlink_toに入れ子で要素を追加したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

```
<%= link_to "リンクです", {:controller => :hoge_controller, :action => :hoge_action}, class: "hoge_class" %>
```

↓

```
<%= link_to {:controller => :hoge_controller, :action => :hoge_action}, class: "hoge_class" do %>
  <span>hoge</span> リンクです
<% end %>
```

これだとエラーになります。

```
<%= link_to hoge_path, class: "hoge_class" do %>
  <span>hoge</span> リンクです
<% end %>
```

これだと問題ないのですが、コントローラーとアクションを明示的に指定するにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

`link_to` の引数をカッコで囲むことで可能かと思います。

```
<%= link_to({:controller => :hoge_controller, :action => :hoge_action}, class: "hoge_class") do %>
  <span>hoge</span> リンクです
<% end %>
```